# Which and whereis fail to find command?

Tags: pip, which

Why is it sometimes that which and whereis fail to find a command?

e.g.

```
$ awswl
-bash: /Users/geoffrey/Library/Python/2.7/bin/awswl: No such file or directory
$ which awswl
$ whereis awswl
$
```

I installed `awswl` with pip, and there seems to be a bug with the Python2 support, so I uninstalled it with pip and reinstalled with pip3. Having done so, when I run `awswl` I get this error:

```
$ awswl
-bash: /Users/geoffrey/Library/Python/2.7/bin/awswl: No such file or directory
```

This isn't just `command not found`, something is clearly found, seems plausibly a symlink or some other script that would link to awswl.  But neither `which` nor `whereis` is doing a good job of telling me where the thing that is left behind is. Why?

Comment: What does `type -a awswl` say? possibly your shell has hashed the old location

Comment: `$ type -a awswl` results in `-bash: type: awswl: not found`

Comment: I think you may have been right, though -- `hash -r` seems to have caused the awswl error to go 'way.

Comment: So if you make an answer, I can accept it. ;)

Comment: For people finding this from a search this answer goes into more detail https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then